# lamp properties in game

Tags: scripting, game-engine, properties

I am trying to animate a lamp properties in the bge yet since it is not a proper Action or ShapeKey I cannot use the standard logic bricks and I was wondering if there is a way around scripting. 
I can access bpy.data.lamps['Lamp'].energy but whats the way to implement the code in the game ?

Comment: an animation action works for lights.. at least in GLSL. i just check

Comment: You can create an action such as rotation/location/scale but keyframing the color or the energy will not create any action usable in the game or I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to access the energy property in game with this script

```
import bge
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
obj = cont.owner
obj.energy = 1.0
```